# What is the difference in the following SLL declaration

Tags: c, structure, singly-linked-list

Scenario 1:

```
 /*Structure declares a node for Singly Linked List*/
  typedef struct SLL
   {
      int data;
       struct SLL *next;
   }
```

Scenario 2:

```
struct SLL
{
   int data;
    struct SLL *next;
}node;
```

Which is the preferred delcaration for SLL in C?

Comment: Is something missing in the first example?

Comment: Rolled back. Don't change the question once you got an answer. This one is more severe as you even accepted the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first one makes no sense in its current form.

I guess the first one is supposed to be like:

```
typedef struct SLL
{
  int data;
   struct SLL *next;
} SLL;
```

so that it defines the type `SSL` to be `struct SLL`. After that you can declare variables like:

```
SLL node;
node.data = 42;
```

The second example is doing something completely different. It makes a variable `node`. So after that you can directly do:

```
node.data = 42;
```

> Which is the preferred delcaration for SLL in C?

Well, they are completely different and do completely different things so they can't be compared.

However, the first method is what you would normally see, i.e. a type definition.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it out now.

Comment: After your edition, the first one declares a structure SSL and a typedef node and the other declares a structure SSL and a variable named node. Different things.